# Combining html files to a index.html

Tags: html, knockout.js, brunch

I'm using knockout and brunch as a build tool. Brunch monitors the dev-files and builds combined javascript, css files and copies index.html to a "public" directory which is served for local development.

Analogous to how the javascript files are concatenated by brunch, I want to take several html files and combine them (just write each file into the body of an index skeleton file). I want the the generated index.html file to be re-generated whenever any source file changes.

Should I just write my own python script to handle this, or is there something out there that I could use?

Note, I am aware of [requirejs/text](https://github.com/requirejs/text) but I do not like the idea of making requests to fetch templates.

Comment: There are way too many possible solutions for me to give a definite recommendation. I am not familiar with brunch, but from a cursory look I could not find something for it. If you want to stick with Javascript, the similar [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) with the [grunt-includes](https://github.com/vanetix/grunt-includes) task might be worth a look. For more complex needs, look for static site generators. [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) is Githubs battle-tested solution, but in Ruby. For Python, look [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/StaticSiteGenerator).

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful!